# Iterate through a couple of sequences with varying count on a single-go

Tags: ios, swift

I have two sequences of type `[[MyCustomType : String]]`(this is to give my exact sequence type), with old and new values respectively, and I'm looking forward to add/remove/update values from the old array based on the new values that I have. So, I want to make it clear that **the two arrays might vary in count**

I can just run a couple of loops or delete the old array and replace the new array to get things done but I'm looking for **an efficient way to get this done on a single-go** as I'm using this array as a dataSource for my tableView. My oldArray is the array with locally stored values and the newArray is with values after fetch

I've tried `zip(oldArray, newArray)` but the problem here is that the loop executes based on the least number of elements present in the sequences of the tuple. So if I have 0 elements on one sequence, it doesn't even execute

> So, to put simply, I want to compare my array of dictionaries and
>   add/update/remove values on a single loop

I have also searched for answers but couldn't find one that matches my use-case. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you put a real life example just for demo to get better idea?

Comment: I see an array of dictionaries and no tuple, to clarify the question could you add some sample data and expected result?

Comment: My bad, I quoted that to be a tuple having "zip(oldArray, newArray)" in mind. I'll edit the question and add an example. Thanks!

Comment: @LokSN Why don't you delete the old array and use new array?

Comment: Because I'm using this array as a dataSource for my tableView and so deleting and re-populating it everytime doesn't seem to be a good idea

Comment: Okey, you have an array of dictionaries. That's bad architecture in the first place. Convert your dictionaries into `struct`. You will see that it will simplify matters greatly.

Comment: @Sulthan Alright, I made them structs. It has made things better but I still can't find an efficient one-go iteration method to compare a couple of MyStructType arrays. Can you help?

Comment: Can you sort the arrays?  If so, then you should be able to update/delete pretty easily.